# Who are the editors of the Proceedings of the Survey Research Methods Section?

Tags: citations, editors

I want to cite a paper published in the [*Proceedings of the Survey Research Methods Section*](http://ww2.amstat.org/sections/srms/Proceedings/). But I cannot find who the editors are/were or if there are any at all.

Comment: Why do you need to know who the editors are?  You only need the name of the authors when you cite a paper.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche For some conferences, the conference participants can hand in there presented research as proceedings papers. They will be peer reviewed (and possibly rejected) and edited by the editors. So they have some kind of effort and if possible I would like to acknowledge them (like editors of a book).